# C++ Get key pressed in background on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

Hi I am trying to make a c++ program that runs in the background and can perform certain functions on specific key combinations. Is there any way of getting key combinations while the program is running in the background. I would like a way that would work on both Linux and Windows but if that is not possible Linux is more important.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for good reasons, you should use gnu [logkeys](https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/source/checkout).

clone it `git clone https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/`

Comment: A tool isn't good or evil, it's a tool. Even keyloggers have legitimate uses and the best intentioned tools like IRC, e-mail and Internet forums can be used to do bad things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pick up combinations or just keypresses?

There are a **lot** of open-source keyloggers for Linux that you could use to determine the latter.

Github for theju's linux-keylogger using `evdev` resources: [link](https://github.com/theju/linux-keylogger).

Comment: I need combinations but is it hard to get that from keypresses

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how evdev reads combinations, you'd have to read up on it.